# What is the canonical way to write a hasher function for TEqualityComparer.Construct?

Tags: delphi, hash, delphi-xe2

Consider the following record:

```
TMyRecord = record
  b: Boolean;
  // 3 bytes of padding in here with default record alignment settings
  i: Integer;
end;
```

I wish to implement `IEqualityComparer<TMyRecord>`. In order to do so I want to call `TEqualityComparer<TMyRecord>.Construct`. This needs to be supplied with a `TEqualityComparison<TMyRecord>` which presents no problems to me.

However, `Construct` also requires a `THasher<TMyRecord>` and I would like to know the canonical method for implementing that. The function needs to have the following form:

```
function MyRecordHasher(const Value: TMyRecord): Integer;
begin
  Result := ???
end;
```

I expect that I need to call `BobJenkinsHash` on both fields of the record value and then combine them some how. Is this the right approach, and how should I combine them?

The reason I don't use `TEqualityComparison<TMyRecord>.Default` is that it uses `CompareMem` and so will be incorrect due to the record's padding.

Comment: Is the hash value actually needed, in your situation? Otherwise, I assume the value returned is not used anyway, so it can be anything, even a literal value like 1 . Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Rudy The hash value is not needed. And I could return a constant that is true. Or raise an `EMethodNotImplemented` exception. But I was curious how to do it right.

Comment: ah, OK then. Curiosity seems to do something bad to cats, though. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Effective Java (by Joshua Bloch)](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) section about overriding hashCode could be useful. It shows how the individual parts of the object (or record) can be combined to efficiently construct a hashCode.

> A good hash function tends to produce unequal hash codes for unequal
>   objects. This is exactly what is meant by the third provision of the
>   hashCode contract. Ideally, a hash function should distribute any
>   reasonable collection of unequal instances uniformly across all
>   possible hash values. Achieving this ideal can be extremely difficult.
>   Luckily it is not too difficult to achieve a fair approximation. Here
>   is a simple recipe:
>
> 1. Store some constant nonzero value, say 17, in an `int` variable called `result`.
> 2. For each significant field `f` in your object (each field taken into account by the equals method, that is), do the following:
>
>    a. Compute an `int` hash code `c` for the field:  ..... *details omitted* ....
>
>    b. Combine the hash code c computed in step a into
>      result as follows: `result = 37*result + c;`
> 3. Return `result`.
> 4. When you are done writing the `hashCode` method, ask yourself whether equal instances have equal hash codes. If not, figure out why
>      and fix the problem.

This can be translated into Delphi code as follows:

```
{$IFOPT Q+}
  {$DEFINE OverflowChecksEnabled}
  {$Q-}
{$ENDIF}
function CombinedHash(const Values: array of Integer): Integer;
var
  Value: Integer;
begin
  Result := 17;
  for Value in Values do begin
    Result := Result*37 + Value;
  end;
end;
{$IFDEF OverflowChecksEnabled}
  {$Q+}
{$ENDIF}
```

This then allows the implementation of `MyRecordHasher`:

```
function MyRecordHasher(const Value: TMyRecord): Integer;
begin
  Result := CombinedHash([IfThen(Value.b, 0, 1), Value.i]);
end;
```