# Correct way to copy data from TBytes to Array of Byte in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

Given the following:

```
LBytes: TBytes;
LArr: array[1..512] of Byte;
...
SetLength(LBytes, 512);
```

What is the correct Move() call to copy all bytes from LBytes to LArr?

```
Move(LBytes[0], LArr, Length(LBytes)); // works

Move(LBytes[0], LArr[1], Length(LBytes)); // works, too

Move(LBytes, LArr[1], Length(LBytes)); // fail
```

Can someone explain why it makes no difference between using Larr and Larr[1] but makes a difference between LBytes[0] and LBytes?

Comment: LBytes -> points to the pointer of the TBytes, LBytes[ 0 ] points to the first element. LArr is a fixed size array and thus is LArr and LArr[ 1 ] the same (eg points to the first element). The first two are thus correct. Use either whatever you find most readable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can someone explain why it makes no difference between using Larr and Larr[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15924484/505088) but makes a difference between LBytes[0] and LBytes?

That's because `LBytes` is a dynamic array which is, ultimately, a pointer to the array. On the other hand, `LArr` is the array.

Another way to say this is that dynamic arrays are reference types, and fixed length arrays are value types.

In my book, there are two viable ways to do this:

```
Assert(Length(LBytes)<=Length(LArr));
Move(LBytes[0], LArr, Length(LBytes));
```

or

```
Assert(Length(LBytes)<=Length(LArr));
Move(Pointer(LBytes)^, LArr, Length(LBytes));
```

I prefer the latter, because it is resilient to a zero length array when range checking is enabled. In that scenario, the first block of code leads to a run time range check error.

You might also be motivated to avoid such low-level trickery. I have a [utility class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15924484/505088) that allows me to write:

```
TArray.Move<Byte>(LBytes, LArr);
```

The signature of the method is:

```
class procedure Move<T>(const Source: array of T; var Dest: array of T); overload; static;
```

Comment: I like the utility class Move<T>. Is this unit available?