# Dynamic array causing an invalid pointer exception

Tags: arrays, delphi, dynamic-arrays

I have a procedure that takes a dynamic array `TData = TArray<Byte>` as a parameter.

```
procedure DoStuff(const Input: TData);
begin
  // do nothing
end;
```

And a function that returns a dynamic array.

```
function SomeData: TData;
begin
  Result := [1, 2];
end;
```

When I use the procedure in the example below, DoStuff gets the following data (1, 2, 3, 1, 3) but I get an EInvalidPointer exception after DoStuff completes.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin    
  DoStuff([1, 2, 3] + SomeData);
end;
```

Calling `DoStuff([1, 2] + SomeData);` does not result in an error, it seems to get touchy when the array is greater than 4 items. If I use a temp variable to hold the array, DoStuff still gets (1, 2, 3, 1, 2) but there is no error.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Temp: TData;
begin
  Temp := [1, 2, 3] + SomeData;

  DoStuff(Temp);
end;
```

It looks like pointer exception is related to how one of the dynamic arrays are freed when they fall out of scope.

Should I not be using dynamic arrays in this way? When working, this solved my current problem very cleanly.

I also have tried using `array of Byte;` instead of `TArray<Byte>;` but had the same result.

Full test unit:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TData = TArray<Byte>;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure DoStuff(const Input: TData);
function SomeData: TData;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoStuff([1, 2, 3] + SomeData);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Temp: TData;
begin
  Temp := [1, 2, 3] + SomeData;

  DoStuff(Temp);
end;

procedure DoStuff(const Input: TData);
begin
  // do nothing
end;

function SomeData: TData;
begin
  Result := [1, 2];
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has no defects and any errors can only be due to compiler / RTL bugs.

Support for dynamic array literals and the dynamic array `+` operator was somewhat patchy when first released. These features were added in XE7 and I believe that most of the bugs were ironed out by XE8.

My guess would be that you are using XE7, or perhaps a layer version which still contains a more obscure bug than the many obvious ones from XE7.

Your options would seem to be:

1. Update to a later Delphi version.
2. Work around the code by avoiding use of the `+` operator with dynamic arrays and / or dynamic array literals.

I still use XE7 and workaround the issues with my own generic concatenation function. An example of how to do this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15924484/505088

Such workaround help you avoid issues with the `+` operator, but not if the issue is with handling array literals. If your problem is with array literals then you may end up needing to use `TData.Create(1, 2, 3)` in place of `[1, 2, 3]`.

If the defect is present in later versions then please submit a bug report to Embarcadero's Quality Portal.

Comment: Delphi 10.2 Berlin has the same error. Happens when calling System._DynArrayClear the 2nd time when Button1Click ends.

Comment: Correction, 10.2 Tokyo it is.

Comment: I can also reproduce it on 10 Seattle on Win32, but not Win64. Also `takeData(localArray + [4, 5, 6])` seems to work fine whereas `takeData([4, 5, 6] + localArray);` does not.

Comment: Using the `TData.Create(1, 2, 3)` in place of the constant expression `[1, 2, 3]` still causes the pointer exception.
I should have mentioned that I was using XE8 but had also reproduced the issue on 10.2.

Comment: As other people have been able to reproduce the error I am submitting a bug report.